# Pyqt5: как изменить содержимое виджета не меняя основного окна

Tags: python, pyqt5

Делаю десктоп приложение на python3+pyqt5, которое состоит из нескольких компонентов:

- menu/

  - menu.py
  - menu.ui
- main/

  - main.py
  - main.ui
- app/

  - app.py
  - app.ui
- default/

  - default.py
  - default.ui

  Мне необходимо реализовать переключение между отображениями разных компонентов в одном окне. Т.е. есть главное окно, разделенное по горизонтали на две части двумя виджетами и нужно отображать в верхнем виджете меню, взятое из menu/menu.py, а в нижнем виджете содержимое виджета из default/default.py при включении программы, и менять содержимое этого виджета при клике на кнопке в меню на app/app.py.

  Я не конвертирую .ui файлы в .py и работаю с ними так:

  ```
   uic.loadUi("main/main.ui", self)
   self.hello_button.clicked.connect(self.print_text)
  ```

  Скажите пожалуйста с помощью каких классов, методов pyqt5 можно вставлять и менять содержимое виджетов в главном окне из виджетов других компонентов программы.

  Я пробовал различные способы с hide() и show(), но это не решает данную задачу. Документацию я изучал, но огромное количество классов запутывают при поиске верного решения, плюс документация эта для c++ и мне как новичку сложновато в ней разобраться так же быстро как, например, с документацией по python.

  Заранее благодарю всех за ответы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете посмотреть класс `QStackedWidget`. Данный класс позволяет добавить несколько виджетов в стэк, а затем отображать именно тот, который вам нужен, меняя `index`.

Comment: Большое спасибо,  похоже это именно то, что нужно. Даже с первого раза получилось показывать содержимое импортированного виджета.